# The expandable plus sign of my treeView exist always even if my node doesn't have any child

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I constructed a treeView WPF MVVM with the help of this very good [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) Then I created a contextMenu for some node that allowed me to add children from selected parent.

The problem is: when I create a new node, it comes with the expandable plus sign or my new node doesn't have any child!

how can I correct this.

```
public class TreeViewItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
#region Data
    static readonly TreeViewItemViewModel DummyChild = new TreeViewItemViewModel();

readonly ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel> _children;
readonly TreeViewItemViewModel _parent;

bool _isExpanded;
bool _isSelected;

#endregion // Data

#region Constructors

protected TreeViewItemViewModel(TreeViewItemViewModel parent, bool lazyLoadChildren)
{
    _parent = parent;

    _children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel>();

    if (lazyLoadChildren)
        _children.Add(DummyChild);
}

// This is used to create the DummyChild instance.
private TreeViewItemViewModel()
{
}

#endregion // Constructors

#region Presentation Members

#region Children

/// <summary>
/// Returns the logical child items of this object.
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel> Children
{
    get { return _children; }
}

#endregion // Children

#region HasLoadedChildren

/// <summary>
/// Returns true if this object's Children have not yet been populated.
/// </summary>
public bool HasDummyChild
{
    get { return this.Children.Count == 1 && this.Children[0] == DummyChild; }
}

#endregion // HasLoadedChildren

#region IsExpanded

/// <summary>
/// Gets/sets whether the TreeViewItem 
/// associated with this object is expanded.
/// </summary>
public bool IsExpanded
{
    get { return _isExpanded; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _isExpanded)
        {
            _isExpanded = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
        }

        // Expand all the way up to the root.
        if (_isExpanded && _parent != null)
            _parent.IsExpanded = true;

        // Lazy load the child items, if necessary.
        if (this.HasDummyChild)
        {
            this.Children.Remove(DummyChild);
            this.LoadChildren();
        }
    }
}

#endregion // IsExpanded

#region IsSelected

/// <summary>
/// Gets/sets whether the TreeViewItem 
/// associated with this object is selected.
/// </summary>
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return _isSelected; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _isSelected)
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
}

#endregion // IsSelected

#region LoadChildren

/// <summary>
/// Invoked when the child items need to be loaded on demand.
/// Subclasses can override this to populate the Children collection.
/// </summary>
protected virtual void LoadChildren()
{
}

#endregion // LoadChildren

#region Parent

public TreeViewItemViewModel Parent
{
    get { return _parent; }
}

#endregion // Parent

#endregion // Presentation Members

#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

#endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members
```

MyXml:

```
`<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Regions}" IsEnabled="{Binding EnableTree}" >
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!-- 
    This Style binds a TreeViewItem to a TreeViewItemViewModel. 
    -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
       <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="AddCity"  ItemsSource="{Binding AddCityItems}"/>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
      DataType="{x:Type local:StateViewModel}" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
      >
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ContextMenu="{StaticResource AddCity}">
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\Region.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RegionName}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>`
```

MyRegionViewModel(below I add my code to create contextMenu for adding child and all code above you can find it in the [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode))

```
public class StateViewModel : TreeViewItemViewModel {
readonly State _state;
   public ICommand AddCityCommand { get; private set; }
   public List<MenuItem> AddCityItems { get; set; }
public StateViewModel(State state, RegionViewModel parentRegion)
    : base(parentRegion, true)
{
    _state = state;
    AddCityItems = new List<MenuItem>();
    AddCityCommand = new DelegateCommand<CancelEventArgs>(OnAddCityCommandExecute, OnAddCityCommandCanExecute);
    AddCityItems.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Add City", Command = AddCityCommand });
}

public string StateName
{
    get { return _state.StateName; }
}

protected override void LoadChildren()
{
    foreach (City city in Database.GetCities(_state))
        base.Children.Add(new CityViewModel(city, this));
}


bool OnAddCityCommandCanExecute(CancelEventArgs parameter)
{
    return true;
}

public void OnAddCityCommandExecute(CancelEventArgs parameter)
{
    var myNewCity = new city();
    Children.Add(new CityViewModel(myNewCity, this));
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't SOLVED and add an answer in the question. That's not how we do it around here.  You can add an answer below yourself with the solution.  Select it as correct in order to close out this question.

Comment: but I said it can be a solution. I was waiting for another purpose !!

Comment: If you are having a hard time understanding, please ask for clarification on [meta]

Answer (score 1):

You might really need to understand it's program logic a bit better.

It's the problem of the "lazyload feature" the sample project provides

You might have notice that the "expandable indicator" is always available on Region and state level but not in city level. And the different is the "islazyload" flag in the constructor. It is a design problem for the so-called generic treelist that actually ASSUME certain node will ALWAYS has children node but the leaf node will NEVER has children node (CityViewModel) didn't even implement the LoadChildren method for crying out loud.

And as I mentioned last time is that the implementation is very nasty for the existence of "DummyChild". That DummyChild is the nasty hack the creator of that project used to make a parent node "Pretend" to have children before the node "IsExpand" and then load up the real child at the IsExpand setter. Let me stress on it again. I think that's an awful hack to ever exist.

For a quick fix of this problem, just set the isLazyLoad flag to false in all level and Load all Children at the constructor. Then the "Expandable indicator" would be reflecting the real status of the node.

Comment: Ok. So to start, of course I noticed the existence of "expandable indicator" and I try to play with it but was unsuccessful because in my case I can create my treeview either from loading it using file either from create it node by node using ContextMenu. So if  expandable indicator always null, I can't load it from file.
Second I'm not agree with you that this implmentation is nasty as the article is the most popular in the net and it's a generic approach.
BTW, see the edit if you want to know the solution of my question.
thank you,

Comment: Your change is the reason why I said the design of the treelist is nasty. well, imagine someone who don't know about everything of the treelist. Is that ever possible for the others know the reason why the node need to set IsExpand to true in constructor and then set it back to false after some logic when the looking at the constructor alone ? You are implementing things just to get things work and that's what I normally call a hack. There's a lot of ways to get things done. You don't need to use MVVM at all for WPF programming but it's bad not to follow the right design.

Comment: TreeVIEW not TreeLIST. According to MVVM wpf, I agree with you that it's a best design using at the wrong time and in the wrong project. but it's the rules of the game. BTW in my project I have many things that become more easier with MVVM just with TreeView it's an exception.
I believe that every developer is looking for generic class that allow him to achieve goal with "imlementing things". So that's why I said the approach using in the article can be good. I will be happy if you suggest me another approach to implement TreeView with full respect of WPF MVVM

Comment: =) ... calm down. I believe you are not the creator of that TREE LIST, okey ? I've been telling you all along. I mainly have problem on the DummyChild thing. Try remove that bit out and you'll fine everything will make a lot more sense as it is. For the lazy load bit, just implement a logic which load the Childrens' Childrens and keep a flag in the node marking IsChildNodeLoaded to avoid duplicate load. 

Anyway, I'm just here answering questions and provide suggestion in my own point of view. Of cause everyone has their freedom to do things in their own way. I'm not your boss =)

Comment: :) oh friend... I'm just trying to defend my code. Don't worry I'm not the creator of this TREEVIEW. Look at this link please https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q529855